# Generating table from dataframe with proportions of 20 variables, for each row, for each possible combination of said variable in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, combinatorics

I have a dataframe with 1000 rows representing a different species, for each of these rows are 20 columns with different proportions of a single variable (amino acids).

For each row (species), I would like to calculate the proportion of each possible combination of single letter variables (amino acids).

So each species should have 10 million calculated combinations of the amino acids.

My code for generating all possible combinations of amino acids is this:

```
S <- c('G','A','L','M','F','W','K','Q','E','S','P','V','I','C','Y','H','R','N','D','T')

allCombs <- function(x) c(x, lapply(seq_along(x)[-1L], 
                                    function(y) combn(x, y, collapse = "")),
                          recursive = TRUE)
Scombi <- allCombs(S)
```

My dataframe looks like this:

```
+----------------------------+----------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|          Species           |  Domain  | Actual OGT |         A         |         C         |         D         |         E         |         F         |         G         |         H         |         I         |         K         |         L         |         M         |         N         |         P         |         Q         |         R         |         S         |         T         |         V         |         W         |         Y         |
+----------------------------+----------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| Acaryochloris_marina       | Bacteria |         25 | 0.089806129655016 | 0.011179368033588 | 0.052093758404379 | 0.056116688487831 | 0.033311792369428 | 0.074719969063287 | 0.021456955206517 | 0.062874293719234 | 0.046629846831622 | 0.105160548187069 | 0.023372745414207 | 0.034667218445279 | 0.050847279968411 | 0.052372091362254 | 0.054393907299958 | 0.058415776607691 | 0.059282788930956 | 0.075786041807662 | 0.012266709932789 | 0.025246090272826 |
| Acetobacter_pasteurianus   | Bacteria |         26 | 0.113635842586218 | 0.009802006063102 | 0.053600553080754 | 0.058133056353357 | 0.036903783608575 | 0.085210142094237 | 0.021833316616858 | 0.053123968429941 | 0.045353753818743 | 0.096549489115246 | 0.025913145427995 | 0.027225003296464 | 0.052562918173042 | 0.033342785074972 | 0.072705595398914 | 0.049908591821467 | 0.056094207383391 | 0.079084190962059 | 0.010144168305489 | 0.018873482389179 |
| Acetobacterium_woodii      | Bacteria |         30 | 0.074955804625209 | 0.011863137047001 | 0.058166310295556 | 0.071786218284636 |  0.03424697521635 | 0.075626240308253 | 0.018397399287915 | 0.087245372635541 | 0.078978610001876 | 0.087790924875632 |  0.03068806687375 | 0.046498124583435 | 0.036120348133785 | 0.031790536900726 | 0.045179171055634 | 0.050727609439901 | 0.055617806111571 | 0.069643619533744 | 0.005984048340735 | 0.028693676448754 |
| Acetohalobium_arabaticum   | Bacteria |         37 |  0.07294006171749 | 0.008402092275195 | 0.063388830763099 | 0.094174357919767 | 0.032968396601359 | 0.074335444399095 | 0.014775170057021 | 0.081175614650614 | 0.068173658934912 | 0.096191143631822 | 0.023591084039018 | 0.042176390239929 | 0.036535950562554 | 0.032690297143697 | 0.045929769851454 |  0.05201834344653 | 0.049098780255464 | 0.079225589949997 | 0.004923023531168 | 0.027286000029819 |
| Acholeplasma_laidlawii     | Bacteria |         37 | 0.067353087090147 | 0.002160134400001 | 0.056809775441953 | 0.065310218890485 | 0.038735792072418 | 0.069508395797039 | 0.018942086187746 | 0.081435757342441 | 0.084786245636216 | 0.096181862610799 | 0.026545056054257 | 0.045549913713558 | 0.038323250930165 | 0.033008924859672 | 0.047150659509282 | 0.054698408656138 | 0.059971572823796 | 0.072199395290938 | 0.005926270925023 |  0.03540319176793 |
| Achromobacter_xylosoxidans | Bacteria |         30 | 0.120974236639852 | 0.008469732379263 | 0.054028585828065 | 0.055476991380945 | 0.035048667997051 | 0.086814010110846 |  0.02243157894653 | 0.050520668283285 | 0.039296015271673 | 0.099074202941835 | 0.028559018986725 | 0.025845147774914 | 0.049701994138614 | 0.034808403369533 | 0.073998251525545 | 0.050072992977641 | 0.051695040348985 | 0.080314177991249 | 0.011792085285623 | 0.021078197821829 |
+----------------------------+----------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

So you can see, each row has the proportion of each amino acid (A,G,I etc.) over the entire set of amino acids, (all 20 add up to 1), but I would like to generate each possible combination, over 1. so something that looks like the following:

```
+----------------------+----------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|       Species        |  Domain  | Actual OGT |         A         |        AC         |        AD         |        AE         |
+----------------------+----------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| Acaryochloris_marina | Bacteria |         25 | 0.089806129655016 | 0.191179368033588 | 0.1782093758404379 | 0.186116688487831 |
+----------------------+----------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

So for each species, 10 million columns (each representing one of the possible combinations of amino acids, without repetition, so the largest string is 20 with each one)

Apologies for being unclear, does anyone have any ideas on how to create this data-set? (Or the best way of asking/explaining what I should be looking up?)

```
Species <- structure(list(Species = c("Acaryochloris_marina", 

"Acetobacter_pasteurianus", 
"Acetobacterium_woodii", "Acetohalobium_arabaticum", "Acholeplasma_laidlawii", 
"Achromobacter_xylosoxidans"), Domain = c("Bacteria", "Bacteria", 
"Bacteria", "Bacteria", "Bacteria", "Bacteria"), Actual.OGT = c(25, 
26, 30, 37, 37, 30), A = c(0.089806129655016, 0.113635842586218, 
0.074955804625209, 0.07294006171749, 0.067353087090147, 0.120974236639852
), C = c(0.011179368033588, 0.009802006063102, 0.011863137047001, 
0.008402092275195, 0.002160134400001, 0.008469732379263), D = c(0.052093758404379, 
0.053600553080754, 0.058166310295556, 0.063388830763099, 0.056809775441953, 
0.054028585828065), E = c(0.056116688487831, 0.058133056353357, 
0.071786218284636, 0.094174357919767, 0.065310218890485, 0.055476991380945
), F = c(0.033311792369428, 0.036903783608575, 0.03424697521635, 
0.032968396601359, 0.038735792072418, 0.035048667997051), G = c(0.074719969063287, 
0.085210142094237, 0.075626240308253, 0.074335444399095, 0.069508395797039, 
0.086814010110846), H = c(0.021456955206517, 0.021833316616858, 
0.018397399287915, 0.014775170057021, 0.018942086187746, 0.02243157894653
), I = c(0.062874293719234, 0.053123968429941, 0.087245372635541, 
0.081175614650614, 0.081435757342441, 0.050520668283285), K = c(0.046629846831622, 
0.045353753818743, 0.078978610001876, 0.068173658934912, 0.084786245636216, 
0.039296015271673), L = c(0.105160548187069, 0.096549489115246, 
0.087790924875632, 0.096191143631822, 0.096181862610799, 0.099074202941835
), M = c(0.023372745414207, 0.025913145427995, 0.03068806687375, 
0.023591084039018, 0.026545056054257, 0.028559018986725), N = c(0.034667218445279, 
0.027225003296464, 0.046498124583435, 0.042176390239929, 0.045549913713558, 
0.025845147774914), P = c(0.050847279968411, 0.052562918173042, 
0.036120348133785, 0.036535950562554, 0.038323250930165, 0.049701994138614
), Q = c(0.052372091362254, 0.033342785074972, 0.031790536900726, 
0.032690297143697, 0.033008924859672, 0.034808403369533), R = c(0.054393907299958, 
0.072705595398914, 0.045179171055634, 0.045929769851454, 0.047150659509282, 
0.073998251525545), S = c(0.058415776607691, 0.049908591821467, 
0.050727609439901, 0.05201834344653, 0.054698408656138, 0.050072992977641
), T = c(0.059282788930956, 0.056094207383391, 0.055617806111571, 
0.049098780255464, 0.059971572823796, 0.051695040348985), V = c(0.075786041807662, 
0.079084190962059, 0.069643619533744, 0.079225589949997, 0.072199395290938, 
0.080314177991249), W = c(0.012266709932789, 0.010144168305489, 
0.005984048340735, 0.004923023531168, 0.005926270925023, 0.011792085285623
), Y = c(0.025246090272826, 0.018873482389179, 0.028693676448754, 
0.027286000029819, 0.03540319176793, 0.021078197821829)), .Names = c("Species", 
"Domain", "Actual.OGT", "A", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", 
"K", "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "V", "W", "Y"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It isn't clear to me how `A = 0.089806129655016` and `C = 0.011179368033588` turn into `AC = 0.191179368033588`. What is the translation formula?

Comment: The numbers in the output file were just random sorry!

Comment: A dataframe with 10 million columns is *not* the right data structure to store this information. You're going to want a sparse matrix or something.

Comment: or better yet: suffix tree

Comment: Would R still be appropriate for this in that case, or would you recommend something like pandas?

Comment: `R` is fine. `Pandas` is just a `python` implementation of the dataframe, so you'll have the same problem there. As I mentioned in my reply to your comment in the other version of this question, there are a lot of mature libraries out there for rapid and memory-efficient counting and storage of kmers for [r](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kmer/index.html), [python](https://github.com/dib-lab/khmer), [C](http://www.cbcb.umd.edu/software/jellyfish), etc. I'm not sure what your downstream goal is, but it basically looks like a kmer counting problem to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure that R is the right tool for this job. It's going to take a very, very long time.  You may be able to reduce that time using the `parallel` package if you have sufficient cores, however.

I've put together a process that will accomplish what you want. For each species, it takes my computer about eight minutes to generate the "joint proportion." If you run on a single thread, as R will do inherently, you're looking at close to an hour just to accomplish the these six species in your sample data.

I wrote my script to run in parallel, and using seven cores, it took about 11 minutes to complete all six. Extending this over all 1000 species, I wouldn't be surprised if it took as long as two days to do all this (on seven cores). If you have a large cluster, you may be able to cut it down some.

Please note that this will not give you your results as described in your question.  I posted a comment that I wasn't sure what formula you were using to get the joint proportions.  I am just taking the sum here for ease of demonstration.  You will need to adjust your code appropriately.

```
library(parallel)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)    

# Reshape data. This will make it easier to split and access proportion
# within each species.
SpeciesLong <- 
  Species %>% 
  gather(protein, proportion,
         A:Y) %>%
  arrange(Species)

# Get unique species 
S <- unique(SpeciesLong$protein)

# Build the combination list
# Note, this is different than your code, I added FUN = paste0
Scombi <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(S),
                        function(x) combn(S, x, FUN = paste0, collapse = "")))

# Function to get the joint proportion
# I took the sum, for convenience.  You'll need to replace this
# with whatever function you use to get the joint proportion.
# The key part is getting the correct proteins, which happens within
# the `sum` call.
joint_protein <- function(protein_combo, data){
  sum(data$proportion[vapply(data$protein, 
                             grepl, 
                             logical(1),
                             protein_combo)])
}

# make a list data frames, one for each species
SplitSpecies <- 
  split(SpeciesLong,
        SpeciesLong$Species)

# Make a cluster of processors to run on
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)

# export Scombi and joint_protein to all processes in the cluster
clusterExport(cl, c("Scombi", "joint_protein"))

# Get the aggregate values for each species in a one-row data frame.
SpeciesAggregate <- 
  parLapply(cl,
            X = SplitSpecies,
            fun = function(data){
              X <- lapply(Scombi, 
                          joint_protein,
                          data)
              names(X) <- Scombi
              as.data.frame(X)
            })

# Join the results to the Species data
# You may want to save your data before this step.  I'm not entirely 
# sure I did this right to match the rows correctly.
Species <- cbind(Species, SpeciesAggregate)
```

Comment: Thank you, I have access to 3500+ cores, so time isn't a problem! This is great though, I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: What's the best way of getting my csv into the dataframe? I noticed you edited my comment, but there are 1090 species, so doing it manually would take a while!

Comment: Sorry what I meant was how do I go importing the dataframe as you did with the sample data, I can read the csv into the environment, but then putting it into your code is being problematic:

`bigdatacsv <- read.csv("AminoAcidspeciesdataEdmundMoody.csv")`

`Species <- structure(list(bigdatacsv)`

Seems to throw errors in the works

Comment: Oh. sorry for the misunderstanding.  Once I got the sample data into the data frame, I ran `dput(Species)` and copied the result into the edited question.

Comment: Great, thanks!

`bigdatacsv <- read.csv("AminoAcidspeciesdata.csv")

Species <- dput(bigdatacsv)`
Seems to run! My laptop is now making loud noises, I feel it may be cluster time. Thanks again!